# Custom PropertySource in Springboot prevents some properties from loading

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I defined custom `PropertySource` in spring boot, that performs decryption of properties. Everything works fine when I request property values in my application code, however I noticed that some properties that are used/loaded by the framework. ( I log every property that is requested via PropertySource)

i.e. following are not loaded:

```
http.mappers.json-pretty-print=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=....
server.ssl.key-store=....
server.ssl.key-store-passsowrd=....
server.ssl.key-password=....
```

I noticed though, that if my PropertySource extednds `EnumerablePropertySource<Properties>` everything works as expected.

Why is that ? Why do I have to extend EnumerablePropertySource ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Boot uses a `DataBinder` when it's [binding configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/bind/PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java). A `DataBinder` requires a `PropertyValues` implementation as a source for the properties that are to be bound. Part of the `PropertyValues` contract is to provide access to all of the known property values. An adapter, [`PropertySourcesPropertyValues`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/bind/PropertySourcesPropertyValues.java) is used to expose all of your application's `PropertySource`s as a `PropertyValues` implementation. If your custom `PropertySource` isn't an `EnumerablePropertySource` then the adapter's unable to access of all of its properties so they aren't included.